# MS hotfix delayed delivery

Tags: email, hotfix

I just requested a hotfix from support.microsoft.com and put in my email address, but I haven't received the email yet. The splash page I got after I requested the hotfix said:

> **Hotfix Confirmation**
>
> We will send these hotfixes to the following e-mail address:
>
> ```
>  (my correct email address)
> ```
>
> Usually, our hotfix e-mail is delivered to you within five minutes. However, sometimes unforeseen issues in e-mail delivery systems may cause delays.
>
> We will send the e-mail from the “hotfix@microsoft.com” e-mail account. If you use an e-mail filter or a SPAM blocker, we recommend that you add “hotfix@microsoft.com” or the “microsoft.com” domain to your safe senders list. (The safe senders list is also known as a whitelist or an approved senders list.) This will help prevent our e-mail from going into your junk e-mail folder or being automatically deleted.

I'm sure that the email is not getting caught in a spam catcher.

How long does it normally take to get one of these hotfixes? Am I waiting for some human to approve it, or something? Should I just give up and try to get the file I need some other way?

(*Update*: Replaced "me@mycompany.com" with "(my correct email address)" to resolve [Martín Marconcini's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297/ms-hotfix-delayed-delivery#30356) ambiguity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took about a day for me when I requested one so I suspect some sort of manual/semi-automated process has to complete before you get the e-mail.

Give it a day before you start bugging them ;)

Answer (score 1):

It usually arrives within the first hour. BUt the fact that it reads me@mycompany.com could either because you put it there to protect your privacy (in which case forget about this) or that the system didn't catch your email and they sent it to me@mycompany.com.

If the email address was ok and you didn't get it, somehow it bounced or it won't arrive. I'd suggest you contact them again providing an alternate email (gmail or such) to make sure that you don't experience any problems.

Last time I received a hotfix it took them 10 minutes.

Good luck with that!